# SmtpClient fails to send email

Tags: vb.net, smtp

My website (I'll call it mydomain.com) is hosted on a dedicated server from 1&1 running Windows Server 2008 R2. For antivirus protection, it has AVG File Server Edition 2013. Windows Firewall is not enabled.

On that server I have installed SmarterMail and use it for all my email through a subdomain mail.mydomain.com. From my site, I send email and it's working fine.

Today I set up an account for email hosting with Rackspace and am trying to test it as a replacement for hosting on my own server. I'm testing with a different domain, myotherdomain.com. I have set up two user accounts in Rackspace as well as Outlook on my local system to send and receive email for this new domain, and it works fine in Outlook.

However, when I try to send email from my site, I get an error. Here is the VB.NET code I'm using in Page_Load of my test page:

```
Dim Msg As New MailMessage("orders@myotherdomain.com", "customer@yahoo.com")

With Msg
  .Subject = "Email test"
  .Body = "This is a test message."
  .IsBodyHtml = True
End With

Dim Smtp As New SmtpClient

With Smtp
  .UseDefaultCredentials = False
  .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("orders@myotherdomain.com", strPassword)
  .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
  .EnableSsl = True
  .Host = "secure.emailsrvr.com"
  .Port = 465
End With

Try
  Smtp.Send(Msg)

  lblMessage.Text = "Success!"

Catch SmtpEx As SmtpException
  lblMessage.Text = "SMTP exception: " & SmtpEx.Message
  If SmtpEx.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then lblMessage.Text &= " (InnerException: " & SmtpEx.InnerException.Message & ")"

Catch GeneralEx As Exception
  lblMessage.Text = "General exception: " & GeneralEx.Message
End Try
```

I can log in to the Rackspace email portal with orders@myotherdomain.com and the value of strPassword.

The SMTP error message I get from attempting to send email from my site is: Failure sending mail. (InnerException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.)

In my 1&1 Control Panel, I have configured the DNS settings for myotherdomain.com for an IP address that isn't used anywhere else, and I've defined the reverse mapping for that IP address to myotherdomain.com. I have also specified that it uses another mail server and have defined the mx0 and mx1 server names, as specified by Rackspace.

Can someone please help with ideas as to why email is not working from my site when it's the domain that is hosted on Rackspace? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across the same issue using Rackspace SMTP. The problem is that the .net SmtpClient doesn't support Implicit SSL, which is what is provided on port 465 on that SMTP server. I switched to using port 587 and it worked correctly.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx

Comment: Not that they have given me accurate information, but since I am having the same issue as OP, I phoned Rackspace email tech support, who told me that they support  Explicit SSL on port 465 at secure.emailsrvr.com.  I have not been able to get SSL to work using that combination.